# I can't install gammu-smsd

Tags: 20.04, usb-modem, gammu

I searched on Google that you can make calls using USB Modem and i was curious to try this. So I installed with success gammu and wammu, but when I want to install gammu_smsd I receive this error (is already downloaded and unpacked but in setting up part it gave me an error):

```
Setting up gammu-smsd (1.41.0-1) ...
Failed to start gammu-smsd.service: Unit gammu-smsd.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gammu-smsd.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gammu-smsd, action "start" failed.
gammu-smsd.service - SMS daemon for Gammu
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit gammu-smsd.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:gammu-smsd(1)

oct 31 06:44:51 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
oct 31 06:44:51 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
oct 31 06:45:57 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
oct 31 06:45:57 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
oct 31 06:52:01 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
oct 31 06:52:01 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
oct 31 06:54:53 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
oct 31 06:54:53 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
oct 31 06:54:54 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
oct 31 06:54:54 Ubuntu-110-15IBR systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
dpkg: error processing package gammu-smsd (--configure):
 installed gammu-smsd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gammu-smsd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me why it happens this?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS btw and I have a Huawei E160 USB Modem which is supported for gammu (found on their page).

**Update:** I tried now opening wammu and it doesn't work... Does anyone knows how can I install the .deb file (which is for older version of Ubuntu) on Ubuntu 20.04?

**Edit:** l -a /var/cache/apt/archives/ -REQUESTED BY Algnis

```
./
../
aircrack-ng_1%3a1.6-4_amd64.deb
alsa-ucm-conf_1.2.2-1ubuntu0.10_all.deb
apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20_all.deb
apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb
apport-gtk_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20_all.deb
apport-gtk_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb
apt-transport-https_2.0.6_all.deb
bind9-dnsutils_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9_amd64.deb
bind9-host_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9_amd64.deb
bind9-libs_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9_amd64.deb
binutils_2.34-6ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
binutils-common_2.34-6ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.34-6ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
brave-browser_1.31.87_amd64.deb
brave-browser_1.31.88_amd64.deb
ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2_all.deb
checkra1n_0.12.4_amd64.deb
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
cpio_2.13+dfsg-2ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
distro-info-data_0.43ubuntu1.8_all.deb
distro-info-data_0.43ubuntu1.9_all.deb
ethtool_1%3a5.4-1_amd64.deb
firefox_93.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
firefox-locale-en_93.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
frei0r-plugins_1.7.0-1build1_amd64.deb
gammu-smsd_1.41.0-1_amd64.deb
gdal-data_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_all.deb
ghostscript_9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
ghostscript-x_9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
gimp_2.10.18-1_amd64.deb
gimp-data_2.10.18-1_all.deb
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
gir1.2-udisks-2.0_2.8.4-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
gnome-control-center_1%3a3.36.5-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.36.5-0ubuntu3_all.deb
gnome-control-center-faces_1%3a3.36.5-0ubuntu3_all.deb
gpart_1%3a0.3-8_amd64.deb
hcxdumptool_5.1.7-1_amd64.deb
hwloc_2.1.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
intel-media-va-driver_20.1.1+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
ipython3_7.13.0-1_all.deb
krita_1%3a4.2.9+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
krita-data_1%3a4.2.9+dfsg-1_all.deb
libappindicator1_12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libarmadillo9_1%3a9.800.4+dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb
libatomic1_10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
libavcodec58_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libavfilter7_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libavformat58_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libavutil56_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libbinutils_2.34-6ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
libblkid-dev_2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb
libbluetooth-dev_5.53-0ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb
libbluray2_1%3a1.2.0-1_amd64.deb
libc++1-10_1%3a10.0.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libc++abi1-10_1%3a10.0.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libc++abi1_1%3a10.0-50~exp1_amd64.deb
libcharls2_2.0.0+dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb
libchromaprint1_1.4.3-3build1_amd64.deb
libctf0_2.34-6ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
libctf-nobfd0_2.34-6ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb
libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb
libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb
libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb
libdbi1_0.9.0-5_amd64.deb
libdbi-dev_0.9.0-5_amd64.deb
libdbusmenu-gtk4_16.04.1+18.10.20180917-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
libdrm2_2.4.105-3~20.04.2_amd64.deb
libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.105-3~20.04.2_amd64.deb
libdrm-common_2.4.105-3~20.04.2_all.deb
libdrm-common_2.4.107-1028_all.deb
libdrm-intel1_2.4.105-3~20.04.2_amd64.deb
libdrm-nouveau2_2.4.105-3~20.04.2_amd64.deb
libdrm-radeon1_2.4.105-3~20.04.2_amd64.deb
libdvdread7_6.1.0+really6.0.2-1_amd64.deb
libegl-mesa0_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
libgbm1_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
libgcrypt20_1.8.5-5ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
libgd3_2.2.5-5.2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
libgdal26_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_amd64.deb
libgdcm3.0_3.0.5-1.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgeos-3.8.0_3.8.0-1build1_amd64.deb
libgeos-c1v5_3.8.0-1build1_amd64.deb
libgfortran5_10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
libgimp2.0_2.10.18-1_amd64.deb
libgl1-mesa-dri_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
libglapi-mesa_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
libglib2.0-dev_2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4_amd64.deb
libglib2.0-dev-bin_2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4_amd64.deb
libglx-mesa0_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
libgme0_0.6.2-1build1_amd64.deb
libgrilo-0.3-0_0.3.12-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libgs9_9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
libgs9-common_9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3_all.deb
libgtkspell3-3-0_3.0.10-1_amd64.deb
libgudev-1.0-dev_1%3a233-1_amd64.deb
libhdf4-0-alt_4.2.14-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libhdf5-103_1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libhwloc15_2.1.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
libhwloc-plugins_2.1.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
libigdgmm11_20.1.1+ds1-1_amd64.deb
libimobiledevice6_1.3.0-3_amd64.deb
libirecovery-1.0-3_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
libirecovery-common_1.0.1-1_all.deb
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
libkmlbase1_1.3.0-8build1_amd64.deb
libkmldom1_1.3.0-8build1_amd64.deb
libkmlengine1_1.3.0-8build1_amd64.deb
liblilv-0-0_0.24.6-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libllvm12_1%3a12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.4_amd64.deb
libltdl-dev_2.4.6-14_amd64.deb
libmbim-glib4_1.24.8-1~20.04_amd64.deb
libmbim-proxy_1.24.8-1~20.04_amd64.deb
libmm-glib0_1.16.6-2~20.04_amd64.deb
libmount-dev_2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb
libmypaint-1.5-1_1.5.1-1_amd64.deb
libmypaint-common_1.5.1-1_all.deb
libmysqlclient21_8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb
libmysqlclient21_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
libmysqlclient21_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_i386.deb
libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
libncurses5_6.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libnetplan0_0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1_amd64.deb
libnss-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
libntfs-3g883_1%3a2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
libopenjfx-java_11.0.7+0-2ubuntu2_all.deb
libopenjfx-jni_11.0.7+0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libopenmpt0_0.4.11-1build1_amd64.deb
libpam0g_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
libpam-modules_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
libpam-modules-bin_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
libpam-runtime_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3_all.deb
libpam-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
libpcap0.8-dev_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb
libpcap-dev_1.9.1-3_amd64.deb
libpcre16-3_2%3a8.39-12build1_amd64.deb
libpcre2-dev_10.34-7_amd64.deb
libpcre2-posix2_10.34-7_amd64.deb
libpcre32-3_2%3a8.39-12build1_amd64.deb
libpcre3-dev_2%3a8.39-12build1_amd64.deb
libpcrecpp0v5_2%3a8.39-12build1_amd64.deb
libpgm-5.2-0_5.2.122~dfsg-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libplist3_2.2.0-4_amd64.deb
libpostproc55_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libpq5_12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
libpq-dev_12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
libprocps8_2%3a3.3.16-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
libpython2.7_2.7.18-1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
libpython2.7-dev_2.7.18-1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
libpython2-dev_2.7.17-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
libpython3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
libpython3.8-stdlib_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
libqmi-glib5_1.28.6-1~20.04_amd64.deb
libqmi-proxy_1.28.6-1~20.04_amd64.deb
libquazip5-1_0.7.6-6build1_amd64.deb
librtaudio6_5.0.0~ds-3build1_amd64.deb
librttr-core0.9.6_0.9.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb
librubberband2_1.8.2-1build1_amd64.deb
libselinux1-dev_3.0-1build2_amd64.deb
libsepol1-dev_3.0-1_amd64.deb
libsmbclient_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb
libsmi2ldbl_0.4.8+dfsg2-16_amd64.deb
libspandsp2_0.0.6+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
libssh-4_0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
libssh-gcrypt-4_0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
libswresample3_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libswscale5_7%3a4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
libtiff5_4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
libtinfo5_6.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libtool_2.4.6-14_all.deb
libtvcontrol0_0.0.1-1_amd64.deb
libudev1_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
libudisks2-0_2.8.4-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libusb-1.0-0-dev_2%3a1.0.23-2build1_amd64.deb
libusb-1.0-doc_2%3a1.0.23-2build1_all.deb
libusbmuxd6_2.0.2-3_amd64.deb
libva2_2.7.0-2_amd64.deb
libva-drm2_2.7.0-2_amd64.deb
libva-wayland2_2.7.0-2_amd64.deb
libva-x11-2_2.7.0-2_amd64.deb
libwbclient0_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.32.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
libwireshark13_3.2.3-1_amd64.deb
libwireshark-data_3.2.3-1_all.deb
libwiretap10_3.2.3-1_amd64.deb
libwsutil11_3.2.3-1_amd64.deb
libx265-179_3.2.1-1build1_amd64.deb
libxatracker2_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
libxnvctrl0_470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
libzmq5_4.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
linux-firmware_1.187.19_all.deb
linux-generic-hwe-20.04_5.11.0.37.41~20.04.16_amd64.deb
linux-generic-hwe-20.04_5.11.0.38.42~20.04.17_amd64.deb
linux-headers-5.11.0-37-generic_5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2_amd64.deb
linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04_5.11.0.37.41~20.04.16_amd64.deb
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04_5.11.0.38.42~20.04.17_amd64.deb
linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-37_5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2_all.deb
linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-38_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_all.deb
linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic_5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2_amd64.deb
linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04_5.11.0.37.41~20.04.16_amd64.deb
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04_5.11.0.38.42~20.04.17_amd64.deb
linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.11.0-37-generic_5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-37-generic_5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb
lock
macchanger_1.7.0-5.4_amd64.deb
materia-kde_20210814-295+pkg3~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb
materia-kde_20211027-300+pkg3~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb
mesa-va-drivers_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
mesa-vdpau-drivers_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.3_amd64.deb
modemmanager_1.16.6-2~20.04_amd64.deb
modem-manager-gui_0.0.19.1-2_amd64.deb
modem-manager-gui-help_0.0.19.1-2_all.deb
netplan.io_0.103-0ubuntu5~20.04.1_amd64.deb
net-tools_1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
ntfs-3g_1%3a2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jre_8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
openjfx_11.0.7+0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
openjfx-source_11.0.7+0-2ubuntu2_all.deb
openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb
oxygen-icon-theme_5%3a5.68.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb
p7zip-rar_16.02-3build1_amd64.deb
papirus-icon-theme_20211001-5525+pkg22~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb
partial/
pixiewps_1.4.2-4_amd64.deb
procps_2%3a3.3.16-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
python2.7-dev_2.7.18-1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
python2-dev_2.7.17-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20_all.deb
python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb
python3-apt_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6_amd64.deb
python3-backcall_0.1.0-2_all.deb
python3-decorator_4.4.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
python3-ipython_7.13.0-1_all.deb
python3-ipython-genutils_0.2.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
python3-jedi_0.15.2-1_all.deb
python3-parso_0.5.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb
python3-pickleshare_0.7.5-2_all.deb
python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.20_all.deb
python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb
python3-prompt-toolkit_2.0.10-2_all.deb
python3-scapy_2.4.3-4_all.deb
python3-traitlets_4.3.3-3_all.deb
python3-update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb
python3-wcwidth_0.1.8+dfsg1-3_all.deb
python-apt-common_2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6_all.deb
python-dev-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb
python-is-python2_2.7.17-4_all.deb
reaver_1.6.5-1_amd64.deb
samba-libs_2%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb
snapd_2.51.1+20.04ubuntu2_amd64.deb
squashfs-tools_1%3a4.4-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
systemd-sysv_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
thermald_1.9.1-1ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb
thunderbird_1%3a78.13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
thunderbird-gnome-support_1%3a78.13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
thunderbird-locale-en_1%3a78.13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
thunderbird-locale-en-us_1%3a78.13.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_all.deb
tshark_3.2.3-1_amd64.deb
tzdata_2021a-2ubuntu0.20.04_all.deb
tzdata_2021e-0ubuntu0.20.04_all.deb
udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb
udisks2_2.8.4-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
unixodbc-dev_2.3.6-0.1build1_amd64.deb
update-manager_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb
update-manager-core_1%3a20.04.10.9_all.deb
usbmuxd_1.1.1-2_amd64.deb
uuid-dev_2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb
va-driver-all_2.7.0-2_amd64.deb
vim-common_2%3a8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.3_all.deb
vim-tiny_2%3a8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
wifite_2.5.2-3_all.deb
winehq-stable_6.0.2~focal-1_amd64.deb
wine-stable_6.0.2~focal-1_amd64.deb
wine-stable-amd64_6.0.2~focal-1_amd64.deb
wine-stable-i386_6.0.2~focal-1_i386.deb
wireless-regdb_2021.08.28-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_all.deb
wireshark-common_3.2.3-1_amd64.deb
xxd_2%3a8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Post the output of `l -a /var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: I updated. You can see now @Algnis

Comment: Thanks found the solution :)

Comment: So, can you tell me exactly what's wrong @Algnis ? :)

Comment: Did as you said

Comment: Upvote and accept if it worked ( ╹▽╹ )

Comment: I hope so you will give me further updates

Comment: Post the error that apt fix broken gave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really this is a bug, it was already reported to launchad as [bug 1877968](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gammu/+bug/1877968). I have just confirmed on my 20.04 LTS box.

It seems that developers forgot to change the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}` variable in the service-file to real path.

On user-level we can fix by using the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i "s|\${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}|/usr/bin|" /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service
sudo apt-get install gammu-smsd
```

then you have to configure Gammu as it was planned.

Comment: I will try later because I can't now. :)

Comment: And thank you for trying to help me :D

Comment: IT WORKED. THANK YOU SO SO MUCH :D